# Array of pointers to class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

I am new programming C++ and I am getting an error that I don't know how to solve. I have a class cell, then I try to create an array of pointers to this class as I show here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class cell{
    public:
    cell(int nx, int ny);
    void allocatePtr();
    float getT() {return T ;}


    float T=10;
    int nx, ny;
    float *ptrW, *ptrE, *ptrN, *ptrS;

};

int main() {

    cell **mesh = new cell *[10];
    for (int i =0; i<10; i++)
    mesh[i]= new cell(10,10);

    cout<<mesh[1]->T<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

But when I run it on a MacBook Pro with Xcode I get this errors:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "celda::celda(int, int)", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You never implemented the constructor, or forgot to link with it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with creating an array of pointers.

Comment: If you're new, I would recommend postponing using pointers and arrays as much as possible until you're comfortable working without them. Over-relying on `new` is a nasty habit that's hard to break.

Answer (score 2):

You did not implement the constructor you call - that's why you're getting linker error. Fix this:

```
class cell
{
public:
    cell(int nx, int ny)
    : nx(nx), ny(ny)
    { }

    void allocatePtr();

    float getT() { return T ; }


    float T = 10;
    int nx, ny;
    float *ptrW, *ptrE, *ptrN, *ptrS;

};
```

**EDIT**

Little explanation what this new code does. Let's create a class:

```
class Sample
{
protected:
    int value;
    float factor;
    void* data;

public:
    Sample(); //(1)
    Sample(const Sample& origin); //(2)
    Sample(int v, float f, void* d);  //(3)
};
```

This class have some members: `int`, `float` and `void*`. It also defines few constructors:
(1) is a default constructor,
(2) is a copy constructor,
(3) is a our custom constructor.

As you know, every member should be properly initialized in constructor, so every object is created in valid state.

We can assign initial value to a member in two ways. Let's define our constructor using both methods:

1) Using assignment operator.

```
Sample::Sample()
{
    this->value = 0;
    this->factor = 0.0f;
    this->data = nullptr;
}

Sample::Sample(const Sample& origin)
{
    this->value = origin.value;
    this->factor = origin.factor;
    this->data = origin.data;
}

Sample::Sample(int v, float f, void* d)
{
    this->value = v;
    this->factor = f;
    this->data = d;
}
```

2) Using initialization list:

```
Sample::Sample()
:    value(0)
,    factor(0.0f)
,    data(nullptr)
{ }

Sample::Sample(const Sample& origin)
:    value(origin.value)
,    factor(origin.factor)
,    data(origin.data)
{ }

Sample::Sample(int v, float f, void* d)
:    value(v)
,    factor(f)
,    data(d)
{ }
```

The second solution is always preferred, because every member is initialized **anyway** (imagine, that there is always such initialization list, even if you don't define it - in this case compiler will initialize all members calling default constructor for each of them), so using assignment inside constructor body, we waste ability to create our object in an efficient way.

It's worth mentioning, that some types of members **have to** be initialized. Example : references. Consider:

```
struct S
{
public:
    int& xr; //'x' is a reference!

public:
    S(const int& x);
};

//This won't even compile, because compiler does not know, how initialize 'rx'.
S::S(const int& x)
{
    this->xr = x; //This is also an error - references cannot be reassigned.
}

//Fine
S::S(const int& x)
: xr(x)
{
}
```

Read more [on this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Comment: thanks It solved it, but as I am new and I have not seen that syntaxis before, could you add a brief explanation like what is what, or example.